# Accessing softwareserial.available in the arduino loop function always return 0 but in the setup function returns the available byte

Tags: softwareserial

I am working on an accident detection system using arduino, what i want to do is to store the recipient phonenumber received as an SMS in the arduino EEPROM, using `Serial1.available()` to check for bytes in the software serial within the loop() function always return 0, but using it in the setup() function work fine, i have tried my best to debug but am not getting, where could i be getting it wrong. the entire code is bellow:

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
SoftwareSerial Serial1(2, 3); //make RX arduino line is pin 2, make TX arduino line is pin 3.
SoftwareSerial gps(10, 11);
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

#define x A1
#define y A2
#define z A3

int xsample = 0;
int ysample = 0;
int zsample = 0;

#define samples 10

#define minVal -50
#define MaxVal 50

int i = 0, k = 0;
int  gps_status = 0;
float latitude = 0;
float logitude = 0;
String Speed = "";
String phoneNumber = "";
String gpsString = "";
char *test = "$GNRMC";

void initModule(String cmd, char *res, int t)
{
  while (1)
  {
    Serial.println(cmd);
    Serial1.println(cmd);
    delay(100);
    while (Serial1.available() > 0)
    {
      if (Serial1.find(res))
      {
        Serial.println(res);
        delay(t);
        return;
      }

      else
      {
        Serial.println("Error");
      }
    }
    delay(t);
  }
}

void writeString(char add, String data)
{
  int _size = data.length();
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < _size; i++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(add + i, data[i]);
  }
  EEPROM.write(add + _size, '\0'); //Add termination null character for String Data

}

String read_String(char add)
{
  int i;
  char data[100]; //Max 100 Bytes
  int len = 0;
  unsigned char k;
  k = EEPROM.read(add);
  while (k != '\0' && len < 500) //Read until null character
  {
    k = EEPROM.read(add + len);
    data[len] = k;
    len++;
  }
  data[len] = '\0';
  delay(2000);
  return String(data);
}

void receive_store_phoneNumber() {
  String msg = Serial1.readString();
  Serial.println(msg);
  phoneNumber = msg.substring((msg.indexOf("***")) + 3);
  writeString(10, phoneNumber);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Phone num stored");
  delay(2000);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("Accident Alert  ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("     System     ");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Initializing");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Please Wait...");
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("Initializing....");
  initModule("AT", "OK", 1000);
  initModule("ATE1", "OK", 1000);
  initModule("AT+CPIN?", "READY", 1000);
  initModule("AT+CMGF=1", "OK", 1000);
  initModule("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0", "OK", 1000);
  initModule("AT+CMGDA=\"DEL ALL\"", "OK", 1000);
  delay(200);
  Serial.println("Initialized Successfully");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Initialized");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Successfully");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Callibrating ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Acceleromiter");
  for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
  {
    xsample += analogRead(x);
    ysample += analogRead(y);
    zsample += analogRead(z);
  }

  xsample /= samples;
  ysample /= samples;
  zsample /= samples;

  Serial.println(xsample);
  Serial.println(ysample);
  Serial.println(zsample);
  delay(1000);

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Waiting For GPS");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("     Signal    ");
  delay(2000);
  gps.begin(9600);
  get_gps();
  show_coordinate();
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("GPS is Ready");
  delay(1000);
  //  writeString(10, "+2348132450841");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("System Ready");
  Serial.println("System Ready..");

}


void loop()
{
  if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    receive_store_phoneNumber();
  }

  int value1 = analogRead(x);
  int value2 = analogRead(y);
  int value3 = analogRead(z);

  int xValue = xsample - value1;
  int yValue = ysample - value2;
  int zValue = zsample - value3;

  Serial.print("x=");
  Serial.println(xValue);
  Serial.print("y=");
  Serial.println(yValue);
  Serial.print("z=");
  Serial.println(zValue);

  if (xValue < minVal || xValue > MaxVal  || yValue < minVal || yValue > MaxVal  || zValue < minVal || zValue > MaxVal)
  {
    get_gps();
    show_coordinate();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Sending SMS ");
    Serial.println("Sending SMS");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(read_String(10));
    Send();
    Serial.println("SMS Sent");
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("System Ready");
  }
}

void gpsEvent()
{
  gpsString = "";
  while (1)
  {
    while (gps.available() > 0)          //Serial incoming data from GPS
    {
      char inChar = (char)gps.read();
      gpsString += inChar;                   //store incoming data from GPS to temparary string str[]
      i++;
      //     Serial.println("88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888");
      //     Serial.println(inChar);

      if (i < 7)
      {
        if (gpsString[i - 1] != test[i - 1])    //check for right string
        {
          i = 0;
          gpsString = "";
        }
      }
      if (inChar == '\r')
      {
        if (i > 60)
        {
          gps_status = 1;
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          i = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    if (gps_status)
      break;
  }
}

void get_gps()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Getting GPS Data");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Please Wait.....");
  gps_status = 0;
  int x = 0;
  while (gps_status == 0)
  {
    gpsEvent();
    int str_lenth = i;
    coordinate2dec();
    i = 0; x = 0;
    str_lenth = 0;
  }
}

void show_coordinate()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Lat:");
  lcd.print(latitude);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Log:");
  lcd.print(logitude);
  Serial.print("Latitude:");
  Serial.println(latitude);
  Serial.print("Longitude:");
  Serial.println(logitude);
  Serial.print("Speed(in knots)=");
  Serial.println(Speed);
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Speed(Knots):");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(Speed);
}

void coordinate2dec()
{
  String lat_degree = "";
  for (i = 20; i <= 21; i++)
    lat_degree += gpsString[i];

  String lat_minut = "";
  for (i = 22; i <= 28; i++)
    lat_minut += gpsString[i];

  String log_degree = "";
  for (i = 32; i <= 34; i++)
    log_degree += gpsString[i];

  String log_minut = "";
  for (i = 35; i <= 41; i++)
    log_minut += gpsString[i];

  Speed = "";
  for (i = 45; i < 48; i++)   //extract longitude from string
    Speed += gpsString[i];

  float minut = lat_minut.toFloat();
  minut = minut / 60;
  float degree = lat_degree.toFloat();
  latitude = degree + minut;

  minut = log_minut.toFloat();
  minut = minut / 60;
  degree = log_degree.toFloat();
  logitude = degree + minut;
}

void Send()
{
  Serial1.println("AT");
  delay(500);
  serialPrint();
  Serial1.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(500);
  serialPrint();
  Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=");
  Serial1.print('"');
  Serial1.print(read_String(10));    //mobile no. for SMS alert
  Serial1.println('"');
  delay(500);
  serialPrint();
  Serial1.print("Latitude:");
  Serial1.println(latitude);
  delay(500);
  serialPrint();
  Serial1.print(" longitude:");
  Serial1.println(logitude);
  delay(500);
  serialPrint();
  Serial1.print(" Speed:");
  Serial1.print(Speed);
  Serial1.println("Knots");
  delay(500);
  serialPrint();
  Serial1.print("http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=15&mrt=yp&t=k&q=");
  Serial1.print(latitude, 6);
  Serial1.print("+");              //28.612953, 77.231545   //28.612953,77.2293563
  Serial1.print(logitude, 6);
  Serial1.write(26);
  delay(2000);
  serialPrint();
}

void serialPrint()
{
  while (Serial1.available() > 0)
  {
    Serial.print(Serial1.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: only one SoftwareSerial instance can listen. it is set with listen(). https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialListen

Comment: how do i implement that in my code, am so frustrated already, i need hints please

Answer (score 1):

As Juraj stated in the comments, you have 2 instances of `SoftwareSerial`, but only one of them can listen to it's receive pin at the same time (this is because they rely on the same interrupts to sample the pin). When you call `gps.listen()`, you set the `gps` interface to listen on it's receive pin. `Serial1` (the second `SoftwareSerial` instance) will then no longer listen and thus will not receive anything. When you call `Serial1.listen()` it will be vice versa.

So you need to decide, on which interface you want to listen. For example you could try listening to the GPS all the time, and only switch to the other interface, if you want to send or receive an SMS (since the SIM module seems to be only controlled via AT commands, it will not send data spontaneously).

Or, as an alternative, you could switch to a bigger Arduino, which has more hardware serial interfaces, like the Arduino Mega. It has 4 hardware Serial interfaces and all of them are listening at the same time, since it is implemented in hardware, not in software.

Comment: I commented because I was sure this is a duplicate, but I had no time to search for it